# Flutter Google Sign In Method without Firebase but with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, flutter, google-signin

I am developing a mobile application with Flutter, and I'm using MongoDB and Node.js for its backend. In a normal user registration process, I create a registration with information such as username, email address, and password, and I use the bcryptjs hash method for the password. I save this registration to my MongoDB database. Additionally, for user login, I create a token using the jwt.sign method.

I don't want to use Firebase, so I designed the login process as follows: I added Google login, and when the user logs in with Google, I can retrieve the following information using the Future signIn() async function:

```
Future signIn() async {
  final user = await GoogleSignInApi.login();
  if (user == null) {
    print("User not found in the Google database");
  }
  print(user?.email);
  print(user?.photoUrl);
  print(user?.id);
}
```

I want to directly send this information to my backend API (/register) when the user wants to register. I also want to generate a password on the Flutter side, associating it with the user's user.id and user.email. This way, I want to both save the user to MongoDB and use the Google information. If the same user has logged in with Google, for the Login process, I want to use the password generated using the email and user.id, then create a token using the jwt.sign method, and continue in this manner.

This method seems a bit indirect and lengthy. Do you have a shorter or more recommended approach? Since I don't want to use Firebase, can you give me suggestions accordingly? Is there any mistake in my approach? Is it correct?